# Swift error unwrapping nil when data is present

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am passing a `User` object into another segue. For whatever reason I can print out the object and view all the information in the console. I can even unwrap the data but when I go to insert the data into an outlet it crashes.

```
var user : User? {
    didSet {
        if let name = user?.name {
            print(name)
            nameLabel.text = name
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
As you can see the property exists, however as soon as I try to apply it to my `IBOutlet` it crashes....

[image]

Comment: 1. Does you `nameLabel` connected properly. 2. Does the name in storyboard/xib change. Cross check these points.

Comment: Let set data in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Yes my outlets are connected, its super weird because I can set it with nameLabel.text = "I can type whatever but I cant put the name variable"

Comment: @user934902, Outlets get value only after view was loaded, if you set `user` value **before** view is loaded all the outlets are `nil`. So you need to setup `user` value after `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the value from some other controller and `ChatVC` is not loaded then your `nameLabel` is `nil`, you can prevent crash by checking `nil` for it.

```
var user : User? {
    didSet {
        if let name = user?.name  {
            print(name)
            if nameLabel != nil {
                nameLabel.text = name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also if your setting the `nameLabel` where you have created instance of `ChatVC` then instead of doing this you need to set `Label` text in `viewDidLoad` of `ChatVC` like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameLabel.text = user?.name
}
```

Comment: that prevents the crash but still does not get the data in the Label

Comment: No, I had to totally change how I was passing data through in order for it to work. Still doesnt make sense to me why it wasnt working how I had it before and with what you wrote

Comment: @user934902 Can you show code where you are setting this `chatVc.user` ?